# How to print the coordinates from the given string?

Tags: java, arrays, graph, 2d, coordinates

I have encountered this question in one of the interviews that i have attended and i am stumped.

Given an input string like the following we need to print the coordinates obtained at the last character of the string.

Directions:

```
L-Left
U-Up
R-Right
D-Down
X-Delete the previous move.
```

Assumption:

```
start with the coordinates (0,0)
```

Here is how to calculate the output.

Given Input:

```
3L5UR2DDX2LR
```

Let us do step by step.

```
3L - Move 3 points to the left of (0,0) i.e (-3,0)

5U- Move 5 points upper to (-3,0) i.e (-3,5)

R - Move 1 point to the right of (-3,5) i.e (-2,5)

2D - Move 2 points down to (-2,5) i.e (-2,3)

D - Move 1 point further down i.e (-2,2)

x - Delete the previous move.(current value is (-2,3))

2L -Move 2 left to (-2,3) i.e(-4,3)

R- Move 1 Right to (-4,3) i.e (-3,3)
```

The final output is (-3,3)

I am trying to put it in code However, i am not getting a starting point on how to break this.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would see the problem as recognition of move instructions, each of which has an optional **factor** (how many steps) and a mandatory **direction**.  When the factor is omitted, it actually means the value of `1`.

So these can be represented as a pattern in regular expression:

```
    String regex = "(?<factor>\\d*)"
            + "(?<dir>[LURDX])";
```

Once that is done, we just need to map the direction to the corresponding
**change** in co-ordinates (`dx`, `dy`), and then apply the changes (multiplied by the value of factor) as we process the move instructions in a while loop of regex match.

Note that `X` is a special case, which can be handled by always remember 
the last position as `lastX` and `lastY`.

The following is my implementation:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Walk {
    enum Move {
        L   (-1, 0)
        , U (0, 1)
        , R (1, 0)
        , D (0, -1)
        , X (0, 0)
        ;
        private int dx;
        private int dy;
        private Move(int dx, int dy) {
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
        }
        public int getDx() {
            return dx;
        }
        public int getDy() {
            return dy;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "3L5UR2DDX2LR";
        String regex = "(?<factor>\\d*)"
                + "(?<dir>[LURDX])";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int lastX = 0;
        int lastY = 0;
        while (m.find()) {
            String factorString = m.group("factor");
            int factor;
            if (factorString.length()==0) {
                factor=1;
            } else {
                factor=Integer.parseInt(factorString);
            }
            String dirString    = m.group("dir");
            Move move = Move.valueOf(dirString);
            System.out.format("(%d,%d) last was (%d, %d) %d %s -> "
                    , x, y
                    , lastX, lastY
                    , factor, move.name());
            if (move==Move.X) {
                x = lastX;
                y = lastY;
            } else {
                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
                x += factor * move.getDx();
                y += factor * move.getDy();
            }           
            System.out.format("(%d,%d)%n", x, y);
        }
        System.out.format("finally arrive at (%d,%d)%n", x, y);

    }

}
```

The output of this program is this:

```
(0,0) last was (0, 0) 3 L -> (-3,0)
(-3,0) last was (0, 0) 5 U -> (-3,5)
(-3,5) last was (-3, 0) 1 R -> (-2,5)
(-2,5) last was (-3, 5) 2 D -> (-2,3)
(-2,3) last was (-2, 5) 1 D -> (-2,2)
(-2,2) last was (-2, 3) 1 X -> (-2,3)
(-2,3) last was (-2, 3) 2 L -> (-4,3)
(-4,3) last was (-2, 3) 1 R -> (-3,3)
finally arrive at (-3,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following.  This is the algorithm I would use.

1. Take input string.
2. Pass it to a parser method which returns an array of tokens. Each
   token starts with a number and ends with a letter. If two letters
   follow each other, they are considered two different tokens. X is an
   independent token.
3. Pass the array of tokens to a calculate method which returns final
   coordinates.  In the calculate method, read the array returned in
   point 2. After each token is read, do the necessary operation on the coordinates.

Design the Coordinate class like. This will help you solve your problem easily.

```
public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int modifyX(int xDiff){
        return (getX()+xDiff);
    }

    public int modifyY(int yDiff){
        return (getY()+yDiff);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input String: "UUUDULR", output is: {0,3}

Input String: "ULLLDUDUURLRLR", output is: {-2,2}

Below is the simple C++ implementation of the above problem:

```
void findCoordinate(string s)
{
    int dx,dy;
    int x=0, y=0;
    
    for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='U')
        {
            dx=0;
            dy=1;
        }
        else if(s[i]=='D')
        {
            dx=0;
            dy=-1;
        }
        else if(s[i]=='L')
        {
            dx=-1;
            dy=0;
        }
        else if(s[i]=='R')
        {
            dx=1;
            dy=0;
        }
    
        x+=dx;
        y+=dy;
        
    }
    
    cout<<"Coordinates are:"<<x<<" "<<y;
}
```